# Angular 2, global css file for all components including nested components

Tags: angular

```
<div>
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
  <first> first comp <child> Child </child> </first>
  <second> second comp </second>
</div>
```

,  and  are 3 components. I'm trying to put a common css file across all components. I was able to do that for all others except the  component. I tried encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None too.

The problem with not using :host /deep/ is that I have a couple of huge css files which acts as theme (3rd party). I cannot modify that by adding /deep/ to them

I also tried to include the css file in index.html but the I see the same issue. For nested components, css is not being applied.

Here is the Plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/5cBM2RJgu7s9Q4oTQNBY?p=preview

Child is also an  but you can see that it stands out when compared to other h2 elements.

Could any of you please help?

Comment: If you add the CSS to `index.html` then you don't need `/deep/` (which is deprecated `::ng-deep` should be used now because it's compatible with SASS which will drop support for `/deep/` soon)

Comment: Yes. But, my requirement is, I have 2 CSS themes say A and B. My angular application works in an integrated environment(IE) where the theme to be applied depends on the theme applied on the IE. So, I do a service call to get to know which is the applied theme on the IE. So, when I put the css in index.html so that it can be changed by injecting document object like shown below. <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/no-style.css"> this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href',''‌​) When I do this, CSS is not applied for nested components.

Comment: I'm sure it is, except when you use ViewEncapsulation.Native.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `<child>` component is inside another component, it applies styles of `<h2>` on another `<h2>` and scales the heading inside `<child>` component by `1.5em`. Although something like `<h2><h2>Heading 2</h2></h2>` should work as shown [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/7jup6fae/), I am not sure why it does not work in angular app.

In your case, you need to do this in order to apply the styles on child component:

```
h2 h2 {
    font-size: 1em; 
}
```

Also, your global styles should go inside the `styles.css` file. You don't need a shared.css file, also in this way View Encapsulation is not required. I have removed it from you `app.ts` in plunker demo.

Have a look at the updated [**PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/EOyKDtfBmIL3CTB23Wl0?p=preview).

Comment: Yes, global styles should go inside styles.css and if that is added in the stytles array in the angular.cli.json, then the styles would be applied on all the components including the nested components.

Comment: But, my requirement is, I have 2 CSS themes say A and B. My angular application works in an integrated environment(IE) where the theme to be applied depends on the theme applied on the IE. So, I do a service call to get to know which is the applied theme on the integrated machine. That's the reason I put the css in index.html so it can be changed by injecting document object like shown below. 
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/no-style.css">
 this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href','')
When I do this, CSS is not applied for all components.

Comment: That is not what you stated in your question! We spend time giving you answers and you change your question statements afterwards! Sorry cant help with this problem

Comment: FYI, I have not changed my question statement. "The problem with not using :host /deep/ is that I have a couple of huge css files which acts as theme (3rd party). I cannot modify that by adding /deep/ to them", is part of the statement description. Your suggestion was to modify the css which cannot happen in my case. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add encapsulation none to app.component and inlcude your styles to styleUrls: [''] in app.component.ts

Comment: The styles to be added are dynamic. styleUrls does not accept dynamic values. Which css file needs to be applied comes from a service call. Hence, styleUrls wont work in my case.